# Need to chnage multidimensional array key to its array value

Tags: php, arrays

I need to change the multidimensional array key to its array value. Please help. Thanks in advance.

**MY OUTPUT:**

```
[
   {
      "key":"homeSection_title",
      "value":"Mobile App Landing Page",
      "status":1
   },
   {
      "key":"homeSection_subText",
      "value":"Start focusing on your goals and get more things done with Sync mobile application. It's the first app to harness the power of social connections to help you stay focused and get organized",
      "status":1
   },
   {
      "key":"homeSection_mainImage",
      "value":"header-iphone.png",
      "status":1
   }
]
```

I need to change to key to the index for each array and remove the key from all arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the code below --

```
$a = [
            [
                "key" => "homeSection_title",
                "value" => "Mobile App Landing Page",
                "status" => 1
            ],
            [
                "key" => "homeSection_subText",
                "value" => "Start focusing on your goals and get more things done with Sync mobile application. It's the first app to harness the power of social connections to help you stay focused and get organized",
                "status" => 1
            ],
            [
                "key" => "homeSection_mainImage",
                "value" => "header-iphone.png",
                "status" => 1
            ]
        ];
        $newArray = [];
        foreach($a as $arr){
            $newArray[] = array_values($arr);
        }
```

Hope it helps to you.
Thanks